# Command line cURL tool does not dump response headers on failure after continue

Tags: curl

I have a 24x7 monitoring script on Linux that is trying to catch when a naughty HTTP endpoint randomly fails.  `curl` command failures are logged.

Our command: `$ curl --verbose --fail --location --cookie cookiejar.txt --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'X-TOKEN: XYZ' --request POST --data @body.json --dump-header response_headers.txt --output response_body.txt https://example.com/search 2> stderr.txt`

(Interestingly, this command prints *nothing* to STDOUT.)

Since we are posting data, `curl` adds the standard request header `Expect: 100-continue`.  Thus, the server response begins with: `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue`, but then later finishes (on error) with either:

- `HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout`
- `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error`

After the command fails, file `response_headers.txt` is too short (see sample below) and file `response_body.txt` is empty.  This failure response should return headers and an optional body.  If I use Google Chrome Developer Tools, normally all HTTP responses have headers, including errors (5xx).

**Question:** Am I missing another `curl` command argument to dump all HTTP response headers (and body) on failure after continue?

As I recall, with other tests, HTTP GET requests that fail without continue will show response headers and body.  I only experience this issue with HTTP POST -> continue -> fail.

Sample outputs:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
curl command output [stderr.txt]:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* About to connect() to example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 210.205.40.45... connected
* Connected to example.com (210.205.40.45) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
...
> POST /search HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.44 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: ...
> Content-Type: application/json
> X-TOKEN: XYZ
> Content-Length: 8434
> Expect: 100-continue
>
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0  8434    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [data not shown]

100  8434    0     0  100  8434      0   5143  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  8417
100  8434    0     0  100  8434      0   3193  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  4210* The requested URL returned error: 504 Gateway Timeout

100  8434    0     0  100  8434      0   2856  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  3641* Closing connection #0

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 504 Gateway Timeout
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
curl command output [response_headers.txt]:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked for that behavior by using `--fail`. As the man page says:

```
Fail silently (no output at all) on server errors.
```

Comment: The legend!  I will remove the option, but then I need to check HTTP response status code manually from `response_headers.txt`.  No problem.  Can do!  =)